# WCF application no longer attempts using Windows Authentication -- receives only HTTP 401.2

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, kerberos, ntlm

We have a ClickOnce WPF application which communicates via WCF to a service.

Sometime last year, the client was correctly using authentication to communicate with the service after an initial unauthorized attempt:

```
2012-09-20 18:19:08 {ip address} POST /MyService/MyService.svc - 80 - {other ip address} - 401 2 5 0
2012-09-20 18:19:10 {ip address} POST /MyService/MyService.svc - 80 DOMAIN\USERNAME {other ip address} - 200 0 0 2279
```

However, as of late it is no longer attempting to authenticate itself:

```
2013-02-08 11:27:09 {ip address} POST /MyService/MyService.svc - 80 - {other ip address} - 401 2 5 1
2013-02-08 11:27:09 {ip address} POST /MyService/MyService.svc - 80 - {other ip address} - 401 1 2148074254 202
```

As far as I can tell, the config has not been changed in this interim.

The WPF client application's config is set up as:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IShipRecService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="00:00:15"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

and the server with:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="basicBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

So there are a couple of strange things here:

- The security modes on these configs do not match. They should, however: the live instances of the client / web applications *do* work with this set up. Additionally, adjusting the web.config to match does not resolve this problem.
- We also have a web application which has the same config as the WPF client application. This is able to communicate with the service. The only difference I can see here is that they are on the same box.

In IIS 7.5, Anonymous Authentication is disabled for the service and Windows Authentication is enabled.

Any ideas as to what is preventing the client application from attempting Windows authentication? Or how I can go investigating it further?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  Had you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228268/wcf-wshttpbinding-and-disabling-anonymous-access/232142#232142

Comment: Thanks. No I hadn't but I don't quite see the link -- we are using basicHttpBinding here, not wsHttp.
Also, the config setup currently works on one of the servers (Live) but not the other (Staging), so it seems unlikely to be at fault.